# How do I write a csproj XML with signature

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-serialization, .net-6.0

I have written an application that updates the XML in csproj files.   The XML is validly formed, but I get a comparison warning in Visual Studio that the original has a different encoding to the new one.

> Left file: Unicode (UTF-8) with signature.  Right file: Unicode (UTF-8) without signature.

The code that serialises the XmlDocument is like this:

```
        var xmlOutputSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "\t",
            Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true),                
        };
        using var outStream = new StreamWriter(inputFile.FullName);
        using var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(outStream, xmlOutputSettings);
        xmlOutputDocument.WriteContentTo(xmlWriter);
```

The new xml file starts like this, which is identical to the original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

I have looked at various suggestions on SO and the web at how to remove the BOM, but in my case, I DO want a BOM, but this doesn't satisfy Visual Studio.

What else can I try?

Comment: If it is Unicode it should be encoding="utf-16"

Comment: @jdweng Unicode works perfectly well in utf8.

Comment: What libraries are you using?  Then why are you getting errors?

Comment: I'm using the standard `System.Xml` libraries.  Visual Studio 2022 is perfectly happy to  'save with encoding' and choose "Unicode (UTF-8 sign signature)" as the encoding.

Comment: Writing may be3 fine but what are you using to read.

Comment: Visual Studio is reading the csproj files, and it's happy to do so, but the files are supposed to be encoded in UTF8.   It looks like, despite the settings, the code is not writing a BOM to the file.

Comment: Not all characters can be written in UTF-8.  UTF-8 doesn't use encoding.  So you can only use 256 characters (ASCII).  Problem is when an application does a check of xml and see that UTF-8 is at top of file and then finds a unicode character an error gets reported.

Comment: ASCII is NOT UTF-8.   UTF-8 is capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid character code points in Unicode using one to four one-byte (8-bit) code units.

Comment: NO, NO, NO!!!  You only can have 1,112,064 characters when you look at two bytes at a time.  When you have UTF-8 (only 256) at top of file some applications will detect discrepancies.

Comment: I suggest you take it up with the Unicode committee.  They seem to think UTF-8 can do it.  https://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html - "some applications will detect discrepancies" - you mean those that don't support UTF8 properly ?

Comment: The issue has to do with the label on first line of xml file.  I agree the you should be able to pass unicode through an application that uses UTF-8 encoding.  But when an application is performing checking that is a different story.